# How to select fields according to input array in eloquent - laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

`$arr = array('field1', 'field2', 'field3');`

From User Inputs I get array containing Field names.
I have to fetch data from multiple table joins so, The goal is to select respective fields from tables according to table input from array.

```
    $update_co_column = Co_Total_Ia::
                      ->select(current($arr), next($arr), next($arr))
                     //->join('All Joins here')
                       ->where("user_key", "=", session()->get("user_id"))
                       ->where("student_details.deleted_at", "=", null);
```

I tried using PHP array methods, `curret(arr)` and `next(arr)`. It is working, but just as an temporary solution.
Problems in current solution -

- Don't know exact how many fields to fetch
- Need to fetch extra useless field all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it like this:**

```
$fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];

Model::select($fields)->get();
```

**results:**

```
SELECT
  `field1`,
  `field2`,
  `field3`
FROM
  `model`
```